# overlapping an element on top of a parent scroll element

Tags: html, css

Im trying to overlap an element with a absolute position `.tools` outside of its uppermost parent element `#canvas_area` which has an `overflow:scroll`, however this doesn't  seem to work, but it does work if you remove the `overflow:scroll` attribute.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="canvas_area">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="blocks">
       <div class="tools">
         x
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="tools">
         x
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#canvas_area{
  overflow:scroll;  // remove this and it works
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.container{
  position:relative;
}

.blocks{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.tools{
  position:absolute;
  color:green;
  left:-40px;
}
```

I need #canvas_area to have a scroll, is their a way around this?

here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2exn6oq5/

remove `overflow:scroll` from `#canvas_area` and you will see the green x outside the body, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: overflow:scroll means overflow:hidden + add scrollbars to scroll and see whats hidden :(

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus that makes sense, is thier a way for me to make the scroll only work vertically(y) and have the horizontal be shown etc?

Comment: nop, but you could manage a 40px or so padding to include this area inside the overflowed box  https://jsfiddle.net/2exn6oq5/3/ or https://jsfiddle.net/2exn6oq5/4/

Comment: @new_coder321 check my answer may be this can help you.